# Extending WP_UnitTestCase without any Tests

Tags: unit-tests

I want to add some logging to an extension of WP_UnitTestCase.

Like this:

```
class MZMBO_UnitTestCase extends WP_UnitTestCase
{
    public function el($message){
        file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

And

```
include('class-mzmbo-wpunittestcase.php');

class Tests_Session extends MZMBO_UnitTestCase {
    /** some tests **\
    $this->el('some data');
}
```

Then there's a warning:

```
1) Warning
No tests found in class "MZMBO_UnitTestCase".
```

So I add a useless method and the warning goes away.

```
public function test_nothing() {
    $this->assertEquals( true, true );
}
```

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the `MZMBO_UnitTestCase` class as `abstract`:

```
abstract class MZMBO_UnitTestCase extends WP_UnitTestCase
{
    public function el($message){
        file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```